# How to echo images and files within a directory onto a page php

Tags: php, file, directory, echo

```
if ($handle = opendir('.')) {

    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {

        if ($entry != "." && $entry != ".." && !in_array($entry, $blacklist)) {
            echo "<p>$entry\n</p>";
        } 


    }

    closedir($handle);
}
```

Above is the PHP code I am using to echo all the files in a directory. It works fine but the page echoes out this:

example.html

test.php

image.png

mobile.html

text.txt

image2.jpg

How do I make it so that if a file in the directory is an image, that gets shown as an image rather than text. E.g, the page will echo out:

example.html

test.php

[image]
<sub>(source: [treehugger.com](http://media.treehugger.com/assets/images/2011/10/toyota-iq-small-car-001.jpg))</sub>

mobile.html

text.txt

[image]

In short, the code that I am currently using only displays the name of each of the files in the directory. I would like it to display the name of each of the files in the directory but however, if there is an image in the directory, instead of echoing the file name of the image, it instead displays the image.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is a little short on information. Can you share what you have tried, and what problems have you run into?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you if you only want to get images:

```
<?php

    foreach(glob("*.{jpg,png,gif,jpeg}", GLOB_BRACE) as $image)
        echo "<img src='" . $image . "' />";

?>
```

(Note no spaces in between the file extensions otherwise it's not going to work)

If you want all files just use this:

```
foreach(glob("*.*") as $file) {

    if(in_array(pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION), array("jpg", "png", "jpeg", "gif")))
        echo "<img src='" . $file . "' />";
    else
        echo $file . "<br />";
}
```

For more information about `glob()` see the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php

Comment: @Osman You're welcome! BTW: You have a nice side effect from using glob with `*.*` you won't get `.` and `..` :D

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
if ($handle = opendir('.')) {

    $valid_image = array("jpg", "jpeg", "png", "gif");

    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {

        if ($entry != "." && $entry != ".." && !in_array($entry, $blacklist)) {

            $exploded = explode('.', $entry);

            if(in_array(end($exploded), $valid_image))
            {
                 echo '<img src="'.$entry.'">';
            }
            else
            {
                echo "<p>$entry\n</p>";
            }
        } 
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
```

Take care to post valid image path like:

```
echo '<img src="http://example.com/images/'.$entry.'">';
```